# How to not debug xstring and other standard libraries?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm using Visual Studio 2010. Often when I'm debugging something (C++) and I e.g. hit the pause button (Break All) in Visual Studio, the break occurs in a standard library such as xstring, xmemory, etc. I don't care about debugging these libraries... I only want to debug my own code. Is there any way to tell Visual Studio to NOT debug these libraries?

Answer (score 0):

When you hit the pause button (Break All) the debugger breaks into each thread wherever the thread happens to be at the moment.  If you think about it for a moment you'll realize that the debugger can't wait until it's in your code (or whatever the debugger might believe is code you care about).  For example, the thread might be blocked waiting for I/O that will never complete and would therefore never get back to your code.

What you can do is use the call stack to find out where the thread is in your code and set a breakpoint there and run.  Or often just doing "Step Out" operations or even "Step Over" operations will quickly get you back to your code.

Comment: Yes, that's what I do in fact. I was wondering whether there's a way to make it break at the last line in your code before it jumps into standard library code... some kind of setting in VS maybe. In C#, for example, the debugger never goes into .NET libraries.

Answer (score 0):

FOR Visual Studio 2012 Please follow the below procedure.
Open the file "C:\Program Files **(x86)**\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\default.natstepfilter"

and add the rule for function name pattern to ignore. e.g I have added following rule to avoid step into inside the string methods.

**std::basic_string.*NoStepInto**

For more information please refer the 
[Link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andypennell/2004/02/06/how-to-not-step-into-functions-using-the-visual-c-debugger/)